# User defined tie breaker for argsort() in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sorting, args

I have two arrays `v` and `c` (can read as value and cost).

I need to perform `argsort()` on `v` such that if 2 elements in `v` are the same, then they need to be sorted according to their corresponding elements in `c`.

Example

```
v = [4,1,4,4] # Here 0th, 2nd and 3rd elemnt are equal
c = [5,0,30,10]
numpy.argsort(v) = [1,0,2,3] # equal values sorted by index
```

Required output

```
[1,0,3,2] # c[0] < c[3] < c[2]
```

How to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) receives an `order` parameter, from the docs:

> When a is an array with fields defined, this argument specifies which
>   fields to compare first, second, etc.

So you could create a structured array from the two values, and the pass the fields in order:

```
import numpy as np

v = [4, 1, 4, 4]  
c = [5, 0, 30, 10]

s = np.array(list(zip(v, c)), dtype=[('value', 'i4'), ('cost', 'i4')])
result = np.argsort(s, order=['value', 'cost'])

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1 0 3 2]
```